# Setting up the viewport for 2D OpenGL programming on Android

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm trying to use OpenGL for 2D programming on the Android. Right now, I'm at the setup stage; trying to configure my viewport. I've got textures loading and drawing, but I'm having trouble getting them to draw like I want. If possible, I want the origin to be at the top left of the screen, increasing downwards, as that's how my code (carried over from when I previously used the canvas) is set up. I figured this would be easy; something along the lines of translate and flip. When I tried modifying the statements that configure the viewport, I was surprised to see that apparently my application isn't even affected by them. See the code below for the onSurfaceChanged() method of the GLRenderer:

```
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;

    gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    GLU.gluOrtho2D(gl, 0, width, height, 0);
    gl.glColor4x(0x10000, 0x10000, 0x10000, 0x10000);
}
```

I can change these values, or even comment out these lines (except for the glColor4x one) completely and the graphics still display exactly the same. The graphics display at their expected size, with no distortion, and even in the right spot if you take the bottom-left coordinate to be the origin. Here's the drawing routine for my textures, as part of a class representing one drawable object:

```
public void draw(GL10 gl, float x, float y) {
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);
    cropSignature = OpenGLUtil.setTextureCrop(gl,srcRectParam,cropSignature);
    ((GL11Ext)gl).glDrawTexfOES(x, y, 0, width, height);
}
```

Where x,y are the coordinates to draw at, and width,height are the dimensions of the texture, specified on instantiation of this object.

Is the glDrawTexfOES completely bypassing the viewport settings I established? If so, how should I be drawing? And how can I set the OpenGL origin to be at the top-left, increasing downwards? Or is that bad practice, and should I be inverting the rest of my code to comply with that?

Comment: You seem to be missing setting matrix you're assigning orthogonal projection to. You could try adding `gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION)` before loading identity matrix.

Comment: @harism Setting this makes no difference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change it to something like this:

```
// call only one time, when texture needs to be loaded
// (also sometimes neccesary after resuming a paused app)
public void loadTexture() {
    textureId = gl.glGenTextures(1);
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);
    cropSignature = OpenGLUtil.setTextureCrop(gl,srcRectParam,cropSignature);
}

public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
}

public void draw(GL10 gl, float x, float y) {
    gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    if(origin_upper_left) {
        GLU.gluOrtho2D(gl, 0, width, 0, height);
    } else {
        GLU.gluOrtho2D(gl, 0, width, height, 0);
    }

    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();

    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);
    gl.glColor4x(0x10000, 0x10000, 0x10000, 0x10000);
    ((GL11Ext)gl).glDrawTexfOES(x, y, 0, width, height);
}
```

Comment: Tried this, same problem occurs.

Comment: ah sorry, I missed that you want the origin in the upper left. Easy enough. See my edit.

Comment: I thought the same thing would help too, flipping the bottom and top arguments to gluOrtho2D, but the problem seems to be that these statements are being ignored. If I use your code, or even if I replace "width" and "height" with "30" and "30", or some other random values, everything still displays as if nothing was changed.

Comment: @Klazen108: Sorry, I did miss something else: You're using glDrawTexfOES. This completely bypasses the transformation stage. OpenGL defines that textures have their origin in the lower left corner. However instead of using glDrawTexfOES a simple textured quad will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, I did some reading while waiting and came to the same conclusion. I guess it pays to read the whole documentation twice before trying anything ^.^